# Have a form that changes based off what button is pushed but I need to add an add/edit button to this

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a form that changes based off what button is pushed --it changes the and pulls the combo boxes for certain tables, I want to add an button to be able to add a new record to the tables based off what button is pushed and possibly a delete button as well --how do I do this in the code.  Again I am new to coding and just want to make sure this works for adding records to each of the tables that the buttons pull.

```
Private Sub Form_Load()

With Me
    Select Case Me.OpenArgs
        Case Is = "Roles"
                .RecordSource = "tblRole"
                .lblFormHeader.Caption = "ROLES"
                .lblTable.Caption = "Role"
                .cboDescription.ControlSource = "RoleID"
                .cboDescription.RowSource = "SELECT RoleID, RoleDescription FROM tblRole"

                .cboIdentifier.Visible = True
                .cboIdentifier.ControlSource = "RoleTeam"
                .cboIdentifier.RowSource = "SELECT Team_ID, Team_Name FROM tbl_Teams"

        Case Is = "Teams"
                .RecordSource = "Tbl_Teams"
                .lblFormHeader.Caption = "TEAMS"
                .lblTable.Caption = "Team Name"
                .cboDescription.ControlSource = "Team_ID"
                .cboDescription.RowSource = "SELECT Team_ID, Team_Name FROM tbl_Teams"

                .cboIdentifier.ControlSource = vbNullString
                .cboIdentifier.RowSource = nullstring
                .cboIdentifier.Visible = False

        Case Is = "Sites"
                .RecordSource = "Tbl_Site"
                .lblFormHeader.Caption = "SITE"
                .lblTable.Caption = "Site"
                .cboDescription.ControlSource = "Site_ID"
                .cboDescription.RowSource = "SELECT Site_ID, Site_Name FROM Tbl_Site"

                .cboIdentifier.ControlSource = vbNullString
                .cboIdentifier.RowSource = nullstring
                .cboIdentifier.Visible = False

        Case Is = "Managers"
                .RecordSource = "Tbl_Managers"
                .lblFormHeader.Caption = "Managers"
                .lblTable.Caption = "Managers"
                .cboDescription.ControlSource = "Manager_ID"
                .cboDescription.RowSource = "SELECT Manager_ID, Manager_Name FROM Tbl_Managers"

                .cboIdentifier.ControlSource = vbNullString
                .cboIdentifier.RowSource = nullstring
                .cboIdentifier.Visible = False

        Case Is = "AuditApp Role"
                .RecordSource = "Tbl_AuditApp_Role"
                .lblFormHeader.Caption = "AuditApp Role"
                .lblTable.Caption = "AuditApp Role"
                .cboDescription.ControlSource = "AuditAPP_RoleID"
                .cboDescription.RowSource = "SELECT AuditAPP_RoleID, AuditAPP_Description FROM 
                 Tbl_AuditApp_Role"

                .cboIdentifier.ControlSource = vbNullString
                .cboIdentifier.RowSource = nullstring
                .cboIdentifier.Visible = False

        Case Is = "Batch Status"
                .RecordSource = "Tbl_BatchStatus"
                .lblFormHeader.Caption = "Batch Status"
                .lblTable.Caption = "Batch Status"
                .cboDescription.ControlSource = "BatchStatus_ID"
                .cboDescription.RowSource = "SELECT BatchStatus_ID, BatchStatus_Desc FROM 
                 Tbl_BatchStatus"

                .cboIdentifier.ControlSource = vbNullString
                .cboIdentifier.RowSource = nullstring
                .cboIdentifier.Visible = False

        Case Is = "Primary Process"
                .RecordSource = "Tbl_PrimaryProcess"
                .lblFormHeader.Caption = "Primary Process"
                .lblTable.Caption = "Primary Process"
                .cboDescription.ControlSource = "Primary_Process_ID"
                .cboDescription.RowSource = "SELECT Primary_Process_ID, Primary_ProcessDescr FROM 
                 Tbl_PrimaryProcess"

                .cboIdentifier.ControlSource = vbNullString
                .cboIdentifier.RowSource = nullstring
                .cboIdentifier.Visible = False

              Case Is = "Secondary Process"
                .RecordSource = "Tbl_SecondaryProcess"
                .lblFormHeader.Caption = "Secondary Process"
                .lblTable.Caption = "Secondary Process"
                .cboDescription.ControlSource = "SecondaryProcess_ID"
                .cboDescription.RowSource = "SELECT SecondaryProcess_ID, SecondaryProcess_Desc FROM 
                 Tbl_SecondaryProcess"

                .cboIdentifier.ControlSource = vbNullString
                .cboIdentifier.RowSource = nullstring
                .cboIdentifier.Visible = False



        Case Else
            'Something weird happend!
    End Select
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Code could execute an INSERT or DELETE action SQL. Research building SQL statements in VBA and Execute or RunSQL methods.

Comment: Is there not a way to add a button to add a new record to the tables in the code and possibly have a delete button as well, not sure I will actually delete though.  These tables are combo boxes on the form once the button for that process is selected from the main menu.  I just don't want to have to go to the backend of my database to update the tables.

Comment: Yes, a button would run the code I suggested.